# Ответ от запрашиваемой страницы

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

День добрый. Написал вот такую небольшую функцию которая `POST` данными шлет ID фотографии для голосования.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#but1").click(function(){
var photo_id = $('a#but1').attr('photo_id');
$("#loading").show();
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/photo/poll',
data: "photo_id="+photo_id,
success: function(data) {
alert(data);
$("#loading").hide();
},
error:  function(xhr, str){
alert('Возникла ошибка');
$("#loading").hide();
}
});
})
});
</script>
```

И исполняемый файл отвечает запросу.
Что-то ввиде:

```
<?php
echo "Вы уже проголосовали за эту фотографию.";  
OR
echo "Ваш голос успешно принят.";
?>
```

Но вот не задача, мне так-же надо принимать новое значение голосов. и отдавать вместе с результатом запроса. 
ps. PHP файл умеет отдавать переменную `$new_count_vote`
Что почитать или что необходимо сделать?(

Comment: Лучше всего такие вещи отдавать в формате JSON. PHP и JavaScript хорошо работают я этими типами данных.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Используйте параметр `dataType: "json"` и возвращайте данные так

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return_array);
exit;
```

соответственно в `callback data` будет таким-же массивом как и `$return_array;`

Comment: Совершенно верно и правильно)